# REST API using Swagger and Node.js with SQL Server as DB

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, yaml, swagger

I've created a working REST API with Node.js Express that operates CRUD operations within SQL Server. Now, I am given task to document my API using Swagger. However, my API do not have Swagger modules installed during its creation.

I've tried to create a copy of my API using SwaggerHub and generate Node.js server from the API, but found no solution to get it work with SQL Server.

Can anyone please enlighten me on Swagger and how to connect my created Swagger API to SQL Server using Node.js Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger is a set of open-source tools built around the OpenAPI Specification that can help you design, build, document and consume REST APIs

OpenAPI Specification (formerly Swagger Specification) is an API description format for REST APIs

If you already created a swagger definition file for your API then you can use following tools to generate what you need

- [swagger-node-codegen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-node-codegen) - Generate JS,ES6,Express API backend
- [Swagger tool - Swaggercodegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/server-stub-generator-howto#nodejs) - Generates Nodejs code

Either ways you will have to create database connection and map your data into db table and javascript model. Like explained in [here](https://blog.cloudboost.io/adding-swagger-to-existing-node-js-project-92a6624b855b)

Comment: Thanks, Nuwan! I appreciate your answer. I've generated the API in form of node.js server. All that's left is to connect it to a SQL server that I've created. Any tips on editing the controller file so that it matches the value in the server?